# Friends my Friends recently add

Tags: mysql, sql

Im building a platform where users can connect with other users (Social platform)

I have a Table called friends and i am saving the connections like this

```
user_id  |   friend_id  |   request   |   add_date
```

Now i need to write a sql query to get the most recent friends a specific user's friends added that they are or not already friends of the user. Also the user must be accepted.

Think of it as a news feed and i was to see who my friends recently added (the new recently add person can be my friend or not)

So far i have this but works only when my friend added people i already have.

```
SELECT user_main_id AS frmname, friend_id AS type_id, add_date AS date
FROM friends 
WHERE friend_id 
IN 
(SELECT friend_id 
FROM friends WHERE (friend_id='$user_id' OR user_main_id='$user_id') 
AND request=1 AND friend_id!=$user_id) 
AND request=1 AND friend_id!=$user_id AND user_main_id!=$user_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Maybe there is a better why to approach this.

Suggestions? Much appreciated thanks. The connection is bilateral, no difference between user_id and friend_id. Was designed with those names and had to be carried forward.

Sample Record

```
96618   50683   1   2013-05-08 13:44:31
96618   1230    1   2013-04-03 18:28:51
11671   96618   1   2013-04-03 13:26:51
11671   1230    1   2013-03-23 18:26:08
```

Once 96618 connects with 50683 happens. users 11671 for example will get a msg saying your friend 96618 is now friends with 50683

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: you can do a join, better than subselect...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f2.friend_id
FROM friends f1                         # Friends of target user
    INNER JOIN friends f2 
       ON f1.friend_id = f2.user_id     # Friends of their friends
       AND f2.request = 1 
       AND f2.friend_id != f1.user_id
    INNER JOIN friends f3               # Limiting it to mutual friends
    ON f2.friend_id = f3.user_id AND f3.friend_id = f1.user_id
WHERE f1.user_id = 11671 AND f1.request = 1
ORDER BY f2.add_date DESC
```

Please note that with your current table structure, you are going to need two rows for each friendship, one for each direction.  To do it with only one row, you probably want to split it into two tables - friendships and friendship_members.